# Trivial shader with "not enough data provided for construction constructor"

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a fairly trivial vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uvCoord;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 _uvCoord;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
  _uvCoord = uvCoord;
}
```

Which is giving the error:

```
ERROR: 0:13: error(#174) Not enough data provided for construction constructor
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I have tried googling for what causes this sort of error, without avail. Failing that, I have looked through the shader code carefully, but as far as I can see there are no problems with it.

What causes this sort of error, and how can I fix this shader?

Comment: `position` is `vec2`. You are trying to construct `vec4` with 3 parameters (vec2, float).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> vec4(position, 1.0)
> ```

`vec4` construction requires 4 values. `position`, as a `vec2` only provides 2 values, and the float at the end only provides one, so there's one not provided. Hence the error.

Comment: This is correct, but why is it marked as community wiki?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Because it's not my answer; it's Johnny's. But he didn't want to post it as an answer, so I did to make sure that the question isn't considered "unanswered".